# Why does this code using nextInt() loops forever?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Below code,

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Dummy {

    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static int getIntegerInput(String prompt){
        int choice = 0;
        for(;;){
            System.out.print(prompt);
            try{
                choice = sc.nextInt();
                break;
            }catch(java.util.InputMismatchException ex){
                System.out.print("What??? ");
            }
        }
        return choice;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int choice = getIntegerInput("Enter a number: ");

    } //end main
}
```

does not stop for next user input, if the first user input raised an exception.

How do I understand this problem in the above code? placing `sc.next()` in `catch` resolves the problem. But I'm still not clear what is going on under the hood? What is the right approach to resolve this problem?

Comment: Have you read the doc of the Scanner class?

Comment: @AlexisC. Are you talkign about this point? *When a scanner throws an `InputMismatchException`, the scanner will not pass the token that caused the exception, so that it may be retrieved or skipped via some other method.*

Answer (score 2):

When `nextXYZ()` fails to consume a token it leaves it in the `InputStream`. Here, you are looping over the same input endlessly - each iteration, you attempt to consume this token, throw an exception if it isn't an integer, catch it, and try reading it again - forever.

EDIT:
In order to work around this, you could use `next()` to consume that token and move on to the next one:

```
for(;;) {
    System.out.print(prompt);
    try{
        choice = sc.nextInt();
        break;
    } catch(java.util.InputMismatchException ex) {
        sc.next(); // here
    }
}
```

Comment: so what is the approach to pass that token? so that `nextInt` can read another token?

Comment: @overexchange You could use `next()` to consume that token and move on - see my edited answer.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with `Scanner next()` are they will not advances if the match is not found. And the character for which it failed remain in the stream. Hence its very important to advance the scanner if you found non intended character.

You can use `next()` method which actually consumes any character or you can use *skip* method passing skip pattern.

Use `hasNext()` to know whether a valid match is present or not. If not then consume that character using above said methods.

Answer (score 0):

If it doesnt find an int on the next like, it throws an error. This error is then caught by your program, so the break is never hit because the error jumps over it whenever a non-int (including nothing) is found.